# method= with multiple parameters

Tags: ruby

if I have a method with the equal sign at the end:

```
class A
  def property= name, value
    ...
  end
end
```

how do I invoke the method `property=` and pass arguments to it?

Comment: Are you trying to set an array as the property's value, or are you looking for a dictionary-style setter?

Comment: I have a class that has a hash inside. I want to have a method that sets a value for the given key. I could have `set_property(name, value)` but I was thinking maybe I can have a setter that looks nicer.

Comment: You don't. `property=` method can only take a single argument, but it would be an Array, like so: `def property=(value) ... x.property = 'foo', 'bar'` `value` will now be `['foo', 'bar']`

Comment: @akonsu could you show the expected output? which you are looking for from that method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby already has a special setter syntax for key-value pairs. You can see it in use with Hash:

```
phone_numbers = { Bob: "555-555-1234", Francine: "555-555-5678"}
phone_numbers[:Jenny] = "555-867-5309"
```

To get this syntax for your own class, you just do

```
def []=(key, value)
  # set the value however you like
end
```

Comment: @akonsu: But what you asked for doesn't make much sense unless you want everyone using your code to hate you. If you `def p=(a,b)` then people have to `o.send(:p=, a, b)` to call your method and that's not going to make anyone happy.

Comment: @muistooshort yeah, judging from all the comments I think I will just use a normal `def set_property` method. thanks.

Comment: @Chuck I think this answers my question. The way I asked it, makes it seem that I want to have a hash-like behaviour. I decided to use a plain method, not a setter.

Answer (score 1):

here is what I ended up with (thanks to @LeeJarvis for his/her comment):

```
class A
  def property= value
    x, y = value
    p [x, y]
  end
end

A.new.property = 1, 2
```

Comment: how `value` took 1,2 without using `splat` operator?

Comment: I mean it works like that with ruby 1.9, how the heck does it work? i do not know :)

Comment: got it... see `ob.property=(1,2)` not working whereas `ob.property= 1,2` worked well. I am in `ruby2.0`.

Comment: Why in the name of all that is holy would you want to do this instead of the idiomatic solution I gave?

Comment: more simplified one - `>> class A
>>   def property= value
>>     p value
>> end
>> end` try this :)

Comment: @Chuck, I have a class that maintains two hashes internally. I wanted to have two methods to set values in these hashes. having `[]=` does not help because I need to know which hash I want to modify.

Comment: @akonsu: If you don't want to publicly expose the hashes (though if you're allowing external code to modify them, I don't see why not), I personally would just make proxy objects that implement a public interface to the hashes. Something like `class HashWrapper def initialize(hash) @data = hash end def []=(k,v) @data[k]=v end def [](k) @data[k] end end` and then people can do `property[key] = value`.

Comment: @Chuck thanks, this is a great idea! now I see why your reputation score is that high.